# Batch-reverse (repurposing) existing regex statements

Tags: php, regex

Hullo, all. I have a regex question that is making my eyes crossed. I thought I would use my "call a friend" option.

Here is the php regex I often use for validating form input for persons' names: `/^\pL[\pL '-&]*\z/`, which successfully captures all unicode characters, spaces, hyphens, and ampersands (the last for joint names).

In a simple validation scenario, it works thus:

```
if(preg_match("/^\pL[\pL '-&]*\z/",$name)){
    echo 'That doth be a name!';
}
else{
    // error procedure
}
```

As an example, a match for "Donald & Barack Trump-Obama" returns "That doth be a name!", and "Donald & Barack Trump4444Obama" returns an error, because of the number "4".

Now, let's just say that I have *thousands* of these regexes, for various scenarios besides name validation and I want to use them as a regex filter instead of the vacation scenario above.

If I simply do:

```
$filteredName = preg_replace("/^\pL[\pL '-&]*\z/","",$name);
```

then if the name matches perfectly, it returns nothing (`""`).

How can I tell `preg_replace` to take the input "Donald & Barack Trump4444Obama" and return "Donald & Barack TrumpObama"?

Keep in mind, my motivation for asking this is that I have hundreds of regexes to run through the funnel.

Comment: `'-&` is probably not what you want. Do you want a quote, hyphen, or ampersand? If so the `-` should be first, last, or escaped.

Comment: You probably won't be able to _negate_ a more than 1 character at a time regex. But you could use the negated class of all the valid characters first. Then run the regex with the positive class. Example negated: replace `[^\pL '-&]+` with nothing.

Comment: @sln: Crumbs. That's what I was worried about. You suggest something interesting here, though. I'll work through it tomorrow. If any good comes of my work, I will post a follow-up. Thanks and all the best.

Comment: @sln Thank you very much! This worked, though I had to escape the apostrophe: `/[^\pL -\'&]/`. This model allows me to address most of my regexes with a batch find-replace outside of my scripts. If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept the answer. All the best.